# Create proportion of responses across columns

Tags: r

Hello lovely folks of stack overflow:

i am a beginner in R and at the moment i'm trying to create a proportion for each participant in my study of how many close friends they have who are different from them over their total number of friends.

My data from qualtrics is arranged so that participants were able to categorize up to 20 friends as "same" or "different", these responses are arranged in columns from Q34_1_44 to Q34_20_63. Of course not every participant had/rated the whole available 20 close friends, so many columns are almost all empty. Regardless i am trying to create another column that contains a numerical value that is equal to number of different friends/total (so blanks don't matter). i have tried the following (but got stuck as i realized this wasn't an appropriate function (or at least as far as i know):

```
    dataset.clean2 <- mutate(dataset.clean1, diff.friend=ifelse(Q34_1_44=="Different race",))
```

if anyone knows an easy to understand (no matter how tedious) way to find each participant's percentage of different friends your answers would be highly appreciated!

Thanks you so much in advance <3

Comment: Hi! If you could provide some data that would be useful - check out the guidelines on how to make a minimal reproducible example here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 0):

It's expected on this forum that you should include sample data that has the same format as yours. That saves work for people who want to help you and reduces ambiguity, which both help you get your question answered.

For example:

```
my_data <- structure(list(id = 1:5, Q_1 = c(
  "diff", "same", "diff", "same",
  "same"
), Q_2 = c("diff", "diff", "same", "diff", "same"), Q_3 = c(
  "same",
  "diff", "diff", "diff", "same"
), Q_4 = c(
  "diff", "diff", "same",
  "same", "same"
), Q_5 = c("same", "diff", "diff", "diff", "diff")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

One approach using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
my_data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(diff_share = sum(c_across(-id) == "diff")/5)

     id Q_1   Q_2   Q_3   Q_4   Q_5   diff_share
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>      <dbl>
1     1 diff  diff  same  diff  same         0.6
2     2 same  diff  diff  diff  diff         0.8
3     3 diff  same  diff  same  diff         0.6
4     4 same  diff  diff  same  diff         0.6
5     5 same  same  same  same  diff         0.2
```

Comment: hello jon, thank you so much for helping me out with this question. I will definitely include an example data set when next i post questions. i have one remaining question on your solution, i require the proportion to be based on each individual participant's total number of friends as some folks in my data set gave 5 friends, some 10, some 3, etc out of 20. is there anyway to edit your solution to take an individual "diff/n", for example dividing over a column that counts total n/20 columns filled in?

Comment: Sure, I think if the # of friends is in column "num_friends" you could replace 5 with "num_friends".